# Good alternate for Jakarta Taglibs?

Tags: java, html, jsp, taglib

We use [Jakarta Taglibs](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/input-doc/intro.html) to ouput some basic HTML form elements like selects.  It appears this library has been retired..  are there any good alternates?  Looking for something simple that will take a Java `Map` and output it to HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) `<c:forEach>` for this. Each iteration gives a [`Map.Entry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods. Assuming that you've a `Map<String, String>` with option values as map keys and option labels as map values, here's an example:

```html
<select name="foo">
    <c:forEach items="${bean.map}" var="entry">
        <option value="${entry.key}" ${entry.key == param.foo ? 'selected' : ''}>${entry.value}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

As to the replacement of the legacy Jakarta taglib, have a look at MVC frameworks which offers taglibs to bind the model with the view. For example [Struts 1.x](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/index.html) (in essence a slight evolution of the legacy Jakarta taglib), [Struts 2.x](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/index.html) (a further evolution) and [JSF](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) (another evolution in the same direction as Struts 2.x).

Here's an example of how to render a HTML `<select>` in JSF.

```html
<h:selectOneMenu id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

JSF binds it transparently with the model without the need to write your own controller (servlet).

Comment: Standard JSTL is the way to go if you use JSPs.  I'm starting to prefer Velocity for the same use cases.

Comment: And I myself prefer Facelets. But that's another story :)

Answer (score 1):

This project has been retired to attic because almost features are avaibles using standard implementation enmbebed in applicaton servers.

http://attic.apache.org/projects/jakarta-taglibs.html

This project is alive in http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/

Comment: JSTL was arised out of only a small part of the Jakarta taglib. The OP is in essence looking for a replacement of the [`<input:select>`](http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/doc/input-doc/usage.html#select) tag, which isn't available in JSTL.